# Backbone does not return variables to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I'm totally new in programming so excuse me...

When I'm trying to put my data into HTML, it throws me an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined`.  I need to put data from database to HTML through Underscore templates...
What am I'm doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
var AdminView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: "#content",
render: function() {

    var that = this;
    var template = _.template($('#adminpage').html()); //it works and render main template
    that.$el.html(template);
    var test = new UsersCollection();

    test.fetch({
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(test.toJSON());//it works too,showing data in console
            var template = _.template($('#users_table').html(), {
            test: test
            });
            that.$el.html(template);
        }
    });
```

And here goes HTML(table with id 'users_table):

```
<% _.each(test,function(user,key,list){ %>
 <tr>
   <td><%= key %></td>

   <td><%- user.l_name %></td>

   <td><%- user.f_name %></td>

   <td><%- user.login %></td>

   <td><%- user.email %></td>

   <td><%- user.id_role %></td>

   <td>
     <div class="small success btn">


 </tr>
 <% }) %>*/
```

So, I need to put *test* data into this table...  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass 'data' instead of 'test' to the users_table template.

In success function, change test:test to test:data